# compare int before its placed into an array?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, int

Fill an Array with no duplicate numbers. eg 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7: is ok, but 1, 2, **3, 3**, 4, 5,... for example is not?

Comment: google collections jar is nice to use. Where you simply enter in your array or collection, pass an int value, and define a predicate where it wud either return a true if same or false. Thus on a false condition, simply add the number to the list.

Comment: a `Set` and standard IO

Comment: Collection without duplicates -> Set

Comment: You answered the question yourself. A combination of loops and conditional statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is called `LinkedHashSet<Integer>` if you need order or just `Set<Integer>` (any implementation) if you don't

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Set<Integer>`, duplicates will not be stored.

Answer (score 0):

```
    boolean duplicate = false;
    int input = 5;
    int[] a = new int[5];
    for(int x : a){
        if(x == input){
            duplicate = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!duplicate){
        a[pos] = input;
    }
```